# What kind of sensor should we use?

Tags: sensors

In my project we have to detect the different shapes(like washers,bolts etc) of object as well as their type (like steel , plastic,brass) so i am confused what kind of sensor i should use to create this project.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a camera, at least for the shape.  You could make some assumptions about the color of the objects to identify the material as well, but that might not be the most accurate way.

Answer (score 0):

For Detecting the **type of material** you could try using it as a conductor, and check for its resistance value. You can calibrate equipment to specify the product based on electricity conductivity, plastics won't conduct at all metals can be classified roughly based on resistances.

For checking **shapes** you will have to use a camera take images and compare them to a database of similar images, that is if you want high accuracy. Otherwise you can use rotating driver to generate a cam profile of the object, and use it to identify the shape of the object, but that is only possible for bigger objects. for small objects you can only depend upon a camera image comparison.

Comment: Well that object will be placed on a moving belt and i have to differentiate the object in the run time so how would i check the material type.

Also the object can be of oriented differently so Image Processing is a good idea??

Comment: You could create a image database of the object in various views, and then use a micro-controller to compare the images taken by the camera to the images available in the database. But the accuracy will vary based on the quality of the camera used. You may also use a 3d imaging system which uses 3 or 4 cameras and combine the images from each of them to generate a 3d shape of the object but that can be very costly so its all up-to your budget.

Comment: its a simple school project so i sonot have much money taht i can create 3-D image.

Comment: Just use 3 cameras along the three axis don't use 3d imaging system. take 3 images compare every image using a control flow function program to check all three images with images from database and you are done. Some decent cameras with decent quality are not much costly. The main problem here will be making the program and the database of images.